# Delphi Jedi components manual installation

Tags: delphi, jedi

I'm using Delphi CE 10.4, and it has the DCC32.exe disabled line compilation.
I'm trying to manually install Jedi components, in the readme of JCL it says that it's needed to open and edit included file to customize options, in my case, source\include\jcld27win32.inc.
I'm starting to learn Delphi, and I didn't understand whats is it is necessary to do in this file, and didn't find videos showing a manual installation.
Someone who already installed this way could help me?

> Manual Installation Although it is not recommended, a manual
> installation is possible. You will have to manually configure options
> for the library. That is done by modifying an included file. For each
> tool you want to install the JCL in, repeat the following steps:
>
> 1. Open and edit included file to customize options: ... For Delphi 10.4 and C++Builder 10.4 Win32: source\include\jcld27win32.inc ...
> 2. In the IDE, open and compile package Jcl.dpk (or Jcl.bpk for C++Builder) located in a subdirectory of the "packages" directory
>    matching your version of the IDE. This package doesn't have to be
>    installed since it doesn't provide any components.
> 3. If you want to install experts, open package JclBaseExpert.dpk and compile it, then you can install all the experts you want (packages
>    are located in the same directory).

Comment: There shouldn't be anything you need to change for a default installation. When you're more experienced, there may be things in that file you'll want to change to alter the configuration of the JCL, but nothing needs to be done now.

Comment: Not every manual is in video format!

Comment: So I won't be able to install Jedi in Delphi CE?

Give up and go to Lazarus?

Comment: You will find the needed include file here https://github.com/project-jedi/jedi